# Error al subir imagen al servidor

Tags: php, imagen, servidor

hace tiempo pude implementar la carga de imagenes a nivel de servidor y luego forzando una descarga logré sacar la imagen del servidor.. eso me funcionaba perfectamente trabajando de manera local pero al subir la página al hosting me doy cuenta que la imagen no se está guardando correctamente en el servidor... el error que obtengo es que la imagen no se guarda es decir, sí se guarda un archivo ".jpeg" pero en blanco o en ocasiones la imagen sale fragmentada

Código en cuestión...

```
<?php
//codificamos la imagen y la guardamos en el servidor temporalmente
$imagen=$_POST["image"];

$imagen=explode(";",$imagen)[1];
$imagen=explode(",", $imagen)[1];
$imagen=str_replace(" ","+", $imagen);
$imagen=base64_decode($imagen);

file_put_contents("..\images\imagen.jpeg",$imagen);
?>
```

Comment: El código va como texto, además debes describir mejor que error obtienes, checa [ask]

Comment: amigo y que tal asi?

Comment: Insisto con la observación del compañero @BetaM, coloca el código como texto, el código en imagen no es bien recibido. También considera agregar más detalles sobre el problema; cómo ejecutas la función; si obtienes algún error, el stack del mismo. Recuerda que cada detalle puede ser de mucha utilidad.

Comment: vale amigos muchas gracias por sus correcciones, soy nuevo aquí

Comment: has probado con un move_uploaded_file ()? [documentacion](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.move-uploaded-file.php)

Comment: Supongo que estás subiendo las imágenes desde un formulario o algo así. En ese caso: 1º. El formulario debe ser declarado multi-parte; 2º. Las imágenes se recuperan con `$_FILES`, no con `$_POST`. Para verificar si estás recibiendo imágenes, haz un `var_dump($_FILES);`  y dinos qué muestra. Si no muestra nada, entonces cuéntanos cómo haces para pasar las imágenes al servidor y muestra el código al respecto pulsando en [edit].